# Access position of grid layout in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a quick way to access the location I placed certain widget.

For example, if I have a button

```
self.exampleButton = tk.Button(self)
self.exampleButton.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky="EW")
```

Is there a way that I can get the row or column? Something like `self.exampleButton.getPosition`?

Is creating a dictionary to store the information, like `{self.exampleButton:(3,0)}`, the best way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tkinter has a handy `grid_info()` function:

```
info = exampleButton.grid_info()
print((info["row"], info["column"]))
```